# Regular Expression for Blocking a character in begining

Tags: javascript, java, regex

I am facing an issue with a regular expression while trying to block any string which has minus(-) in the beginning of some white listed characters.

```
^(?!-.*$).([a-zA-Z0-9-:#\\,()\\/\\.]+)$
```

It is blocking minus(-) at place and allowing it any where in the character sequence but this regex is not working if the passed string is single character. 
For e.g A or 9 etc.

Please help me out with this or give me a good regex to do the task.

Comment: Why not, `startWith()` method :-)

Comment: Java != JavaScript

Comment: Javascript provides a method (startsWith) for doing that: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_startswith.asp

Comment: Remove the `.` between `)` and `(`.

Comment: Your pattern very specifically matches 2 or more characters. It has a dot followed by a giant character set with the the `+` quantifier. Just change it to a `*` if you want it to work with a single character input. Also, is this Java or Javascript? Two very different languages.

Comment: @CAustin  thanks for the reply. I was looking for regex  for both java and javascript. Since I have to do both side validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern requires at least 2 chars in the input string because there is a dot after the first lookahead and then a character class follows that has `+` after it (that is, at least 1 occurrence must be present in the string).

So, you need to remove the dot. Also, you do not need to escape any special char inside a character class. Besides, to avoid matching strings atarting with `-` a mere `(?!-)` will suffice, no need adding `.*$` there. You may use

```
^(?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9:#,()/.-]+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LjJwhI/1). Remember to escape `/` if used in a regex literal notation in JavaScript, there is no need to escape it in a constructor notation or in a Java regex pattern.

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?!-)` - cannot start with `-`
- `[a-zA-Z0-9:#,()/.-]+` - 1 or more ASCII letters, digits and special chars defined in the character class (`:`, `#`, `,`, `(`, `)`, `/`, `.`, `-`)
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, and you don't want a minus at the beginning, does ^[^-].*  work as a regex for you? Java's "matches" would return false if it starts with minus

Answer (score 0):

There is a method in a `String` class that provides you exactly what you are asking for - it's a `startsWith()` method - you could use this method in your code like this (you can translate it as "If the given String doesn't start with `-`, `doSomething`, in other case do the `else` part, that can contain some code or might be empty if you want nothing to be done if the given String starts with `-` ") :

```
if(!(yourString.startsWith("-"))) {
    doSomething()
} else {
    doNothingOrProvideAnyInformationAboutWrongInput()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that it can help you.

```
^(?!-).*[a-zA-Z0-9-:#\\,()\/\\.]+$
```